# getResouce or getResource method returns null

Tags: java, excel, file, package

I have an `ExcelReader.java` class in the same package as `Sample.xslx`

Im trying to read a file like this

```
URL url = ExcelReader.class.getClassLoader().getResource("com/.../Sample.xlsx");
```

But `url` is null.

**Things I have tried**

```
FileInputStream is  = getClass().getResourceAsStream("com/.../Sample.xlsx");
```

I also tried

```
File f = new File("....");
f.getAbsoluteFile();
```

However, this picks the path where my eclipse has been installed. My project is actually located in another folder.

Comment: What is the path of Sample.xlsx. Is it under src/com/Sample.xlsx ? Why are you using 3 dots... 2 dots is parent, 1 dot is current. 3 dots does not make sense, to me at least.

Comment: cant you do getClass().getResourceAsStream("Sample.xlsx")

Comment: Is the parent directory of com/…/Sample.xlsx in your runtime classpath?

Comment: @Adam I have given dots just for notion where I have many sub folders. com.comanyname.folder1. My project is located at C;\dev\workspace.
Inside src/main/java source folder I have com.companyname.folder1 package and inside this package I have added the Sample.xslx and also the java file which reads the excel file.

Comment: @EduardoDennis I tried but was getting null pointer exception .

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
ExcelReader.class.getClass().getResourceAsStream("Sample.xlsx");
```

From the `.getClass().getResourceAsStream` [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-)

> Before delegation, an absolute resource name is constructed from the given resource name using this algorithm:
>
> If the name begins with a '/' ('\u002f'), then the absolute name of
>   the resource is the portion of the name following the '/'. Otherwise,
>   the absolute name is of the following form: modified_package_name/name
>   Where the modified_package_name is the package name of this object
>   with '/' substituted for '.' ('\u002e').

If you start with `'/'` it will start from root otherwise it will look relative to current directory.